# PostMethod upload file on Android

Tags: android, upload

I use HttpURLConnection as below to uplaod file:

```
String end = "\r\n";
String twoHyphens = "--";
String boundary = "*****";
String UploadURLPath = "upload php path";

    URL url = new URL(UploadURLPath);
    CameraUploadConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    CameraUploadConnection.setDoInput(true);
    CameraUploadConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    CameraUploadConnection.setUseCaches(false);
    CameraUploadConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    CameraUploadConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
    CameraUploadConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/*");
    CameraUploadConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);

    DataOutputStream ds = new DataOutputStream(CameraUploadConnection.getOutputStream());

    ds.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + end);
    ds.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data;" + "name=\"folder\"" + end + end);
    ds.write(SavePath.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    ds.writeBytes(end);
    ds.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + end);
    ds.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data;" + "name=\"Filedata\"; filename=\"");
    ds.write(FileName.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    ds.writeBytes("\"" + end);
    ds.writeBytes(end);

    FileInputStream fStream = new FileInputStream(Path);

    int bufferSize = 1024;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    int length = -1;

    while((length = fStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        ds.write(buffer, 0, length);
        ds.flush();
    }       
    ds.writeBytes(end);
    ds.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + end);
    fStream.close();
    ds.flush();
```

It can upload, but exist some issue.
So I want to modify to PostMethod and HttpClient to upload.
How can I modify it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample of using httpclient and httppost methods

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
            long timeout = 6000;
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, (int) timeout);
            httpclient.setParams(httpParameters);
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(licensingUrl);
            httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            httpPost.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");


            String stringData = "{\"data\":\"to send\"}";

            try 
            {
                httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(string Data));
            } 
            catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) 
            {
                Log.d("Licensing", e.toString());
            }

             try 
                {
                        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

                        statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

Answer (score 1):

I can give you an example class. See if that helps.

```
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import android.util.Log;

public class HttpFileUpload implements Runnable{
        URL connectURL;
        String responseString;
        String Title;
        String Description;
        byte[ ] dataToServer;
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;

        HttpFileUpload(String urlString, String vTitle, String vDesc)
        {
            try{
                connectURL = new URL(urlString);
                Title= vTitle;
                Description = vDesc;
            }catch(Exception ex){
                Log.i("HttpFileUpload","URL Malformatted");
            }
        }

        String Send_Now(FileInputStream fStream)
        {
            fileInputStream = fStream;
            String server_response=Sending();
            return server_response;
        }

        String   Sending(){
                String iFileName = Title;
                String lineEnd = "\r\n";
                String twoHyphens = "--";
                String boundary = "*****";
                String Tag="fSnd";
                String res;
                try
                {
                        Log.e(Tag,"Starting Http File Sending to URL");

                        // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
                        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)connectURL.openConnection();

                        // Allow Inputs
                        conn.setDoInput(true);

                        // Allow Outputs
                        //conn.setDoOutput(true);
                        conn.setDoOutput(true);
                        // Don't use a cached copy.
                        conn.setUseCaches(false);

                        // Use a post method.
                        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

                        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");

                        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);

                        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"title\""+ lineEnd);
                        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                        dos.writeBytes(Title);
                        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

                        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"description\""+ lineEnd);
                        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                        dos.writeBytes(Description);
                        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

                        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + iFileName +"\"" + lineEnd);
                        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                        Log.e(Tag,"Headers are written");

                        // create a buffer of maximum size
                        int bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

                        int maxBufferSize = 1024*1024*100;
                        int bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                        byte[ ] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                        // read file and write it into form...
                        int bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                        while (bytesRead > 0)
                        {
                                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable,maxBufferSize);
                                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0,bufferSize);
                        }
                        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                        // close streams
                        fileInputStream.close();

                        dos.flush();

                        Log.e(Tag,"File Sent, Response: "+String.valueOf(conn.getResponseCode()));

                        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

                        // retrieve the response from server
                        int ch;

                        StringBuffer b =new StringBuffer();
                        while( ( ch = is.read() ) != -1 ){ b.append( (char)ch ); }
                        String s=b.toString();
                        res=b.toString();
                        Log.i("Response-->",s);
                        dos.close();
                }
                catch (MalformedURLException ex)
                {
                        Log.e(Tag, "URL error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
                        res="-1";
                }

                catch (IOException ioe)
                {
                        Log.e(Tag, "IO error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
                        res="-1";
                }
                return  res;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
}
```